# Pgrouting - pgr_kdijkstraCost int limitations

Tags: postgresql, pgrouting

I've been able to map the driving time and distance between different points in a small city, but I would now like to be able to do this for the United States.

However, I've learned that the function pgr_kdijkstraCost is limited by int arguments. I am using postgresql 9.3 with postgis 2 and pgrouting 2 extensions. I would like to have the function accept bigint arguments.

Is there a known way to fix this? Is the source code for the function available (I found pgrouting on github but don't know where the folder with the function is)?.

Answer (score 0):

pgrouting 2.1.0 alpha1 has been release and there is a new functions

`pgr_dijkstra(text,anyarray,anyarray,boolean,out integer,out bigint,out bigint,out bigint,out bigint,out float,out float)
pgr_dijkstra(text,anyarray,bigint,boolean,out integer,out bigint,out bigint,out bigint,out float,out float)
pgr_dijkstra(text,bigint,anyarray,boolean,out integer,out bigint,out bigint,out bigint,out float,out float)
pgr_dijkstra(text,bigint,bigint,out integer,out bigint,out bigint,out float,out float)
pgr_dijkstra(text,bigint,bigint,boolean,out integer,out bigint,out bigint,out float,out float)
pgr_dijkstra(text,bigint,bigint,boolean,boolean)`

These functions accept an array of bigints so you can compute one-to-many and many-to-many solutions like pgr_kdijkstra.